# Gravitoelectromagnetic effect of a rotating disc

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

Assume a thin disc in a vacuum with 2 objects placed along the axis of the disc - one above the disc and one below, each an equal distance from the disc. Each object will feel an identical force of gravitational attraction between itself and the disc.  Now start the disc spinning. Will the force of gravitational attraction between each object and the disc still be identical?

Comment: *Will the force of gravitational attraction between each object and the disc still be identical?* Yes. Remember that the force from magnetic field on a charge at rest is zero. The same would be true for gravitomagnetic field.

Comment: @A.V.S. What about the effect described in https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03301? I don't know if their analysis has been independently checked yet, but a spin-dependent force was also anticipated by Hawking at the end of https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103857884: "This suggests that there may be a spin dependent force between two black holes as indeed one might expect from the analogy between angular momentum and magnetic dipole moment. Unlike the electrodynamic case, the force would be attractive if the angular momenta had opposite directions and repulsive if they had the same direction."

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly: The EM analog of this is the force exerted by spatially varying magnetic field on *magnetic dipole*. So in OP's setup not only disk must be rotating but also object for which the force is measured.